# What is SchemeRegistry in apache and When it should be used?

Tags: java, httprequest, apache-httpclient-4.x, httpconnection

Apache HTTPClient contains `SchemeRegistry` class `(org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry)`

- What is Scheme Registry?
- When can it be used?

What impact does it make if i use scheme registry like below

```
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
registry.register(new Scheme(WEBSERVICE_URI_SCHEME, 80 ,PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
PoolingClientConnectionManager wsConnManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager (registry);
```

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeRegistry.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is Scheme Registry?

Protocol scheme registry maintains a map of connection socket factories per distinct protocol scheme. For instance, HTTPS scheme requires that connections be secured with TLS/SSL. One may also want to customize the way sockets for HTTP and HTTPS schemes are created and initialized by registering a custom socket factory for those schemes.

> What impact does it make if i use scheme registry like below

You end up with a custom protocol scheme (say, `MYHTTP`).

Whenever you execute a request using this scheme (say, `myhttp://somehost/someservice/`) your custom socket factory will be used to create and initialize outgoing connections to the target server.